# php doesn't throw parse errors on production server

Tags: php

I've just migrated my servers to another VPS provider and noticed that a script wasn't running as expected.

After some testing, I noticed that **PHP** *refuses* to throw any information about parse errors.

If (as an example) I attempt to run a non-existent function, I get the message `Call to undefined function` (which is the expected behaviour).

But, if hypothetically I accidentally manage to run `ech "Test";`, instead of receiving the error `syntax error, unexpected double-quoted string`, a 500 error will greet me.

This is how I'm setting my errors at the top of the **PHP** script (as I don't have access to the global config file):

```
ini_set("log_errors", "On");
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/log/file.log");
```

And, when running `php -l filename.php` within the CLI, I get:

> Errors parsing index.php

Why is this the case? I've tried turning on every possible error reporting configuration to no avail.

Comment: Devil’s advocate, do you really want parse errors showing up on production? Anyway, can you use a local php.ini file, or set it through htaccess or Nginx? As for the CLI, that loads a different set of configuration files than your web server does.

Comment: @ChrisHaas No I don't want errors to be visible on production - hence why I'm outputting them to a log. Currently, I'm running the test on a separate, isolated port to the production version.

Comment: Are you seeing the parse errors in the log?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Unfortunately, no :-(. I may be wrong, but I feel like this may be something to do with `display_startup_errors` as it is disabled by default and obviously you can't set it within a PHP script.

Comment: If a fatal parse error occurs, your code (`ini_set`) isn't executed...